# AWS - custom VPC - IGW - EC2 instance not accessible through HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC .I did not create the NAT gateway but created IGW for my public subnet and then launched and EC2 in my public subnet. When I try to hit the public DNS (IPV4) in the browser I am not able to access the instance , I can SSH and access though . I  have configured the security group for inbound all SSH and HTTP and outbound All . Also the route table is updated with the IGW entry . What can be wrong ?

Comment: Are you running anything that is listening on port 80?

Comment: No I dont think so , if you mean on my local machine . on my EC2 , I am running the below mentiond script in my user data                    #!/bin/bash
# Use this for your user data (script without newlines)
# install httpd (Linux 2 version)
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo "Hello World from $(hostname -f)" > /var/www/html/index.html         Also if this helps, another EC2 running in the default VPC works fine .

Comment: Hmm so you're definitely running on localhost, from the ec2 can you access using `curl localhost` ?

Comment: No I get a Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: What does running systemctl status httpd return?

Comment: Unit httpd.service could not be found.

Comment: That indicates that httpd service was not installed on the host

Comment: Can you try running your userdata script manually as the root user?

Comment: yup it worked . but what could be the issue here . I was expecting the user data script would run as it would normally when I launch an EC2 on the default VPC

Comment: Have a look in /var/log/cloud-init.log and /var/log/cloud-init-output.log. Or access the system log from the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're having no httpd service being found on your server, the reason you can not connect is that no httpd service is running to serve traffic over HTTP (port 80).

Try running the user data script manually and ensure you're on a RHEL distribution based instance (such as RedHat, CentOS or Amazon Linux).

If you're running debian based (such as apache) you would instead install it by running the below command.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
systemctl start apache2
```